# linux mq_open ignores mq_msgsize attribute

Tags: c++, linux, mqueue

All, used to think that I was sane, now not so sure.
I am trying to create a message queue whose mq_msgsize attribute is OTHER than 8192, which seems to be the default.  I have attached my code below -- it has a number of printf's showing the value.  If you can point out what I doing wrong, I will be eternally grateful.

```
bool Subscriber::Subscribe( void )
{
   mqd_t  qid;
   bool   brv = false;
   msg_topic_t topic = this->GetTopic();
   struct mq_attr q_attr;
   int rv = 0;

   if (VALID_TOPIC( topic ))
   {
        if (this->GetName().length() > 0)
        {
            string qnamestr = this->GetName();
            if (qnamestr[0] != '/')
            {   
                qnamestr = "/" + qnamestr; 
                this->SetName(qnamestr);
            }
            const char * qname = (const char *) qnamestr.c_str();

            q_attr.mq_msgsize = 256;
            q_attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
            q_attr.mq_flags = O_NONBLOCK;
            q_attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;

            qid = mq_open( qname, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0644, &q_attr );
            if ((mqd_t) -1 != qid)
            {   
                rv = mq_getattr(qid, &q_attr );
                if (rv != 0)
                {   perror(" get_attr1 failed: "); }
                printf(" queue size is now: %d\n", q_attr.mq_msgsize);
                if (q_attr.mq_msgsize > 1024)
                {
                    struct mq_attr old_attr;

                    q_attr.mq_msgsize = 1024;
                    rv = mq_setattr( qid, &q_attr, &old_attr);
                    if (rv != 0)
                    {   perror(" could not update message size: "); }
                    rv = mq_getattr(qid, &q_attr );
                    if (rv != 0)
                    {   perror(" get_attr2 failed: "); }
                    printf(" queue size is now: %d\n", q_attr.mq_msgsize);
                }
                this->SetOutboxID( qid );
                brv = true; 
                DLOG(INFO) << " qid = " << qid << endl;
                MessageCenter * mc = MessageCenter::GetInstance();
                mc->AddSubscriber( (Subscriber *) this );
            }
        }
    }
   drain_queue( this->GetOutboxID());
    return( brv );
}
```

The output looks like this: 
 queue size is now: 8192
 queue size is now: 8192
 queue size is now: 8192

Thank you!

Comment: It is advisable to look for clues by checking return values and error codes and *then* seek for help on stackoverflow. As you ignore return values from functions it is not obvious that you're going to pay attention to whatever people will tell you.

Comment: good point.  I'll do that.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Namely, I mean `mq_*` family functions, of course.

Comment: Ok. here's another answer for you then ;-)

Comment: So I could only point out what you're doing wrong in the comment above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manpage says:

> The  mq_maxmsg  and  mq_msgsize  fields  are set when the message
>   queue is created by mq_open(3)

and

> The only  attribute  that  can  be  modified is the setting of the
>   O_NONBLOCK flag in mq_flags.  The other fields in newattr are
>   ignored.

Comment: You are reading different man pages than I.  mine says:  The mq_flags field contains flags associated with the open message queue description. This field is initialized when the queue is created by mq_open(3). The only flag that can appear in this field is O_NONBLOCK. so, yes, partially right -- the mq_flags field.  It goes on :The mq_maxmsg and mq_msgsize fields are set when the message queue is created by mq_open(3). The mq_maxmsg field is an upper limit on the number of messages that may be placed on the queue using mq_send(3). The mq_msgsize field is an upper limit on the size of messages

Comment: What about next two paragraphs?

Comment: Because my manpage contains all the information you posted. This one seems to match the one on my system: http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_getattr

Comment: Okay, I see that (sneaky of them).  However, when the queue is created, I also specify a size smaller than the default.  Is it not possible to create a message queue with a msg_size less than 8K?

Comment: Well, let me start with saying that I have no idea ;-)
But could it be that you already created the queue once and subsequent `mq_open`s are just opening? Can you try to mount `mqueue` filesystem to see if it's there or try to `mq_unlink` it before recreating with a desired size?

Comment: You get the wizard award!  After rebooting my box, it worked!  Thank you!  (Not sure how I award you -- accept your answer?  Thanks again!